# Why does my TypeScript playground link break when I use Insert Hyperlink?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I was helping someone with a TypeScript problem and found that copying and pasting the link to the (new) TypeScript playground into the Insert Hyperlink box broke the link.

I tried to paste this link to the updated solution:

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&jsx=2#code/PTAEDMEMGsFNQEYEsB2ATVBzAzgWAFBqwDGANpAE7wqQC2s2ADpMfAEqwsAuoA3gaAgBXFMS5IA9ilDEqkLrACipWPRRcAFAEoAXKEgoAngG4CAXwIEQoACoALJNlBdDjeHchODoCY3FTIUlBGCl8CFzdQAGU6RhUbV3gAXj4BUCQ0AH49bC4KLFN8QRp6HLyC80t8Yilc0GxYlQBBCgpIQz0Y2jjYBLcAbQBdUBT%203gy9AHIFXMmAGlAS2CmmtHyDSbMF3iWpgDFSCSpsYiFNwarwETFJaQbulT3r-xQNCfrylEwtfiKZWokKgAdIdMBpJgBJAAi83SaC0hQs%20AIV1EL2ijVgAGEJN0pLB1NpUn8qFwhBRpBo0oIADwYABuAD5qYI%20Pcei02oYgbRIIwNG8FLROpi%20rAtCNGcTWTL0uBBaogRkJb9ZbKaig6uM0AslmYRukhYU1TLSeTpDTGD4UFjSEhiNAkrwiUkpbx6pinmjbm94cZQGYzIydnRYGYacBGIz-SBrPZHKA0BIGIsJDwAO5HaAsmVItVmLR51kRhnMv5acyFAgaupJ2gGmldHo4vEoAk8YDRoA)

But following that link fails. It works if I go back and manually edit the link that was inserted after the `[1] :` in the markdown:

[This one works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&jsx=2#code/PTAEDMEMGsFNQEYEsB2ATVBzAzgWAFBqwDGANpAE7wqQC2s2ADpMfAEqwsAuoA3gaAgBXFMS5IA9ilDEqkLrACipWPRRcAFAEoAXKEgoAngG4CAXwIEQoACoALJNlBdDjeHchODoCY3FTIUlBGCl8CFzdQAGU6RhUbV3gAXj4BUCQ0AH49bC4KLFN8QRp6HLyC80t8Yilc0GxYlQBBCgpIQz0Y2jjYBLcAbQBdUBT+3gy9AHIFXMmAGlAS2CmmtHyDSbMF3iWpgDFSCSpsYiFNwarwETFJaQbulT3r-xQNCfrylEwtfiKZWokKgAdIdMBpJgBJAAi83SaC0hQs+AIV1EL2ijVgAGEJN0pLB1NpUn8qFwhBRpBo0oIADwYABuAD5qYI+Pcei02oYgbRIIwNG8FLROpi+rAtCNGcTWTL0uBBaogRkJb9ZbKaig6uM0AslmYRukhYU1TLSeTpDTGD4UFjSEhiNAkrwiUkpbx6pinmjbm94cZQGYzIydnRYGYacBGIz-SBrPZHKA0BIGIsJDwAO5HaAsmVItVmLR51kRhnMv5acyFAgaupJ2gGmldHo4vEoAk8YDRoA)

Why?

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that the Insert Hyperlink feature changes `+` to `%20` if the link contains a query part, both in the query part and the fragment identifier (hash fragment). TypeScript's new playground uses fragment identifiers that contain `+` characters which are **not** synonymous with `%20`, so the link fails when that conversion is done.

This appears to be a bug in Insert Hyperlink, which [I've reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330151/dont-replace-with-20-in-urls-inserted-via-insert-hyperlink). It doesn't just affect TypeScript playground links, other kinds of links get broken by it as well; see that report for details.

So for the moment, if you use Insert Hyperlink to insert a TypeScript playground link, you'll have to go manually fix the markdown (just highlight it after the `[n] :` and paste the proper link over it).